# What is the Best way to approach filtering an array using radio button inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was Wounding if it possible to set filtering conditions based on responses From a form that contained Radio Buttons if Said radio button selected it filters the array. is there a simpler way of going about this or am I making this more difficult than it is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#resultstest").clone("<tbody></tbody>");
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "js/contacts.json",
  dataType: "json",
  cashe: false,
  success: function (data) {
      $("input[name=college-age]:radio").click(function () {
      if ($('input[name=college-age]:checked').val() == "yes") {
        var filterContacts = data.contacts.filter(function (contact) {
          return contact.group.includes("College");
        });
      }
    });

    $("input[name=education]:radio").click(function () {
      if ($('input[name=education]:checked').val() == "True") {
        var filterContacts = data.contacts.filter(function (contact) {
          return contact.group.includes("High School");
        });
      }
    });

    $("input[name=vet]:radio").click(function () {
      if ($('input[name=vet]:checked').val() == "yes") {
        var filterContacts = data.contacts.filter(function (contact) {
          return contact.group.includes("Veterans");
        });
      }
    });
    $("input[name=housing]:radio").click(function () {
      if ($('input[name=housing]:checked').val() == "yes") {
        var filterContacts = data.contacts.filter(function (contact) {
          return contact.group.includes("Homelessness");
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Considering your code already achieves the desired result, this question may be more suitable for [**StackExchange's CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead :)

Comment: I agree with Obsidian Age. That being said, you're duplicating a lot of code and that can always be mitigated by using a function with parameters.

Comment: Thank you, Will do Obsidian Age, and  zfrisch